# Facebook-login limit concerns

Tags: authentication, facebook-login

I am building iOS and Android apps and am planning to integrate authentication through Facebook. Are there any limits I should be concerned with, like a limit on the number of users that can login using their facebook profiles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting from Facebook's Platform Policies

> If you exceed, or plan to exceed, any of the following thresholds please [contact us](https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/?id=206103619499608) as you may be subject to additional terms: (>5M MAU) or (>100M API calls per day) or (>50M impressions per day).

So, there is a limit of **5M MAU** which can be loosely translated as the number of Users who can use your app without you requiring to submit the [form](https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/?id=206103619499608) for additional terms.